# char array string confusion

Tags: c++, string, char, type-conversion

I'm in trouble and I cannot wrap my head around this myself..

```
// string::operator+= vs +
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;


int main ()
{
    unsigned char array[6]= { 'f','o','o','b','a','r' };
    string name ("works and not");
    cout << name<< endl;
    name ="";
    for(int i=0; i < 6;  i++)
        name += array[i];
    cout << "working: "<< name << endl;
    name ="";
    name = array[1] + array[0] + array[0] + array[3] + array[4] + array[5]; 
    cout <<"not working: "<<  name << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Now I understand that there's some hidden conversion going on in `+=` notation, and I get, that the plus symbol adds the integers of my characters,
and just converts the final value (to 'p').

But I need to combine various chars into one string.. in one line if possible..
since I need to do that more than once (600++ times) and it's already messing the code up.

since this is the first, and most likely last time I need to convert my "array" values to a string, I'd rather NOT change my char array btw.

thank you!

Comment: for testing: http://ideone.com/XfSEYw

Comment: _"I need to do that more than once (600++ times)"_ Huge code smell here.

Comment: [It's a shame your array is of the wrong type](http://ideone.com/aUIowL).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
name = array[1] + array[0] + array[0] + array[3] + array[4] + array[5];
```

The requirement to do this all in one line is your problem. The right-hand side of the `=` is evaluated before the fact that `name` is even considered. And, yes, since those are all `unsigned char`s, all you're getting is `unsigned char` addition.

*If* your `array` were of `char`, there'd be a shortcut:

```
name = std::string() + array[1] + array[0] + array[0] + array[3] + array[4] + array[5];
```

Now the RHS is being built up from a series of `operator+` as applied to a (temporary) `std::string`, and the final concatenated result copy-assigned into `name`. It's pretty ugly but...

But you can't use this with your `unsigned char`s, because there is no `operator+` for `std::string` and `unsigned char`. You've basically designed yourself into a corner so, if you can't use loops or use a `std::string` to start with in the first place, you're SOL.

If you don't mind a bit of refactoring, though, here's a 2015 solution:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    unsigned char array[6] = { 'f','o','o','b','a','r' };
    std::string name;

    for (auto i : {1,0,0,3,4,5})
        name += array[i];

    std::cout << name << '\n';
}
```

#### ([live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/123ed3d0d1a1ea5f))

Comment: Oh.. it's soo easy sometimes, isn't it's not actually too difficult to use signed chars for me, one more line of code.. no big deal, but that didn't came to my mind AT ALL! So thanks a million!!!!

Comment: @itsid: No problem. As a bonus, I've put a proper, modern solution into my answer.

Comment: Oh I like the 2015 solution! ... hmm.. time to step up I guess :D